# How do you embed a base64 image into json?

Tags: json, html, image, base64

I created a digital ad in adobe animate and have to edit the html so that everything is in one file. The image files and javascript cannot be separate. I have been trying to find a solution for two days now. My experience with coding is limited, so I apologize for any stupid questions!

Here is my code, I am trying to replace `images/Diesel Army 300x600 No Template B_atlas_NP_.jpg` with the base64 image code:

```
lib.properties = {
    width: 300,
    height: 600,
    fps: 30,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    opacity: 1.00,
    webfonts: {},
    manifest: [
        {src:"images/Diesel Army 300x600 No Template B_atlas_NP_.jpg", id:"Diesel Army 300x600 No Template B_atlas_NP_"}
    ],
```

Comment: did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images

Comment: Read the description of tags befoe adding. "embedded" does not mean what you think.

Comment: @Gaurav Singh Faujdar I did look at that question and several others. I have tried many different solutions. I tried adding base64 image as an <img> element and also as a css background, among other things. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do the orange highlighted No's represent in manifest: